# Delete line and update order

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains lines starting with a number, for example

```
1 This is the first line
2 this is the second line
3 this is the third line
4 This is the fourth line
```

What I want to do is delete a line for example line 2 and update the numbering so the file would look like the following, I want to do this in a bash script.

```
1 This is the first line
2 this is the third line
3 This is the fourth line
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

IMO it might be a little easier with `awk`:

```
awk '!/regex/ {$1=++x; print}' inputFile
```

In the `/.../` you can put the `regex` that occurs on the line that needs to be deleted.

#### Test:

```
$ cat inputFile
1 This is the first line
2 this is the second line
3 this is the third line
4 This is the fourth line

$ awk '!/second/ {$1=++x; print}' inputFile
1 This is the first line
2 this is the third line
3 This is the fourth line

$ awk '!/third/ {$1=++x; print}' inputFile
1 This is the first line
2 this is the second line
3 This is the fourth line

$ awk '!/first/ {$1=++x; print}' inputFile
1 this is the second line
2 this is the third line
3 This is the fourth line
```

***Note:** Since we are re-constructing the `$1` field, any white space sequences will get removed.*

Comment: As a side-effect, that `awk` program will replace all white-space sequences in the lines of the file with single spaces. That might not be desirable; it should at least be documented.

Comment: If it matters, it's possible to save the whitespace using string replacement instead of field replacement: `sub(/[0-9]+/, ++x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this set of commands:

```
grep -v '^2 ' file | cut -d' ' -f2- | nl -w1 -s' '
```

1. Using `grep` with `-v` option allows to remove line #2.
2. `cut` program cuts the first column which is line number.
3. Finally, we just need to renumber the lines so we use `nl`.

Comment: @rici: You can easily modify it - `grep -v '^2 '`